# CSRF not set when making an ajax call from jquery to Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am getting a CSRF cookie not set when making an ajax call from jquery to django views.index (I have tried everything i have seen on other stackoverflow posts, see list at bottom of post)

My ajax call:

```
board.delete_comment = function(){

$(this).closest("div").slideUp()
$.ajax("http://localhost:8000/"+$(this).val(),{
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
};
```

My views.index function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete_me(comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    comment.delete()
    return "success"
```

My URL pattern:

```
url(r'^(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete_me, name='delete'),
```

Upon calling the delete_comment function in javascript a 403 forbidden error is triggered. I have tried everything i have seen on existing stack overflow boards:

```
-installing and adding corsheaders to settings
-including a @csrfexempt decorator in views.index
-setting CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to false in settings
-adding the csrftoken header to the request (per django documentation)
-setting a CSRF_TOKEN on the window in my html
```

Nothing seems to work... Anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve this issue? Or what the issue may be.

Comment: Since you have `csrf_exempt`, it shouldn't matter about the token at all, do you have multiple python instances running?

Comment: Are you sure this request is being routed to that view? Do you have other url patterns that might match an ID on its own?

Comment: @Sayse no only one instance of python is running

Comment: @Daniel Roseman yes the request is being routed to the correct view.

Comment: I doubt that. Not only are you seeing a CSRF error when you explicitly marked it as exempt, but you would also get a TypeError because you are not returning an HttpResponse.

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman - This is the url request copied from my browser: http://localhost:8000/2. Also i have now removed the @csrfexempt and i confirmed that the csrftoken is being added to the request header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a cross-domain issue since you are hard-coding http://localhost:8000/ in your ajax call. This could be why the request is being rejected. Try to replace 'http://localhost:8000/' with '/' if this is the url you are targeting.

Comment: Thank you so much! this fixed the problem. It makes sense since i had to remove the !this.crossDomain condition was evaluating false.

Comment: I had the same problem recently. Glad it helped you. Peace